# Two encryption algorithms - Which one is better?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography

I've made 2 encryption algorithms, where one of them focuses on speed, and the other is a stronger encryption.

The first encryption is this:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes, string key)
{
    byte[] Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (index >= key.Length) index = 0;
        bytes[i] += Key[index];
        index++;
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

While this encryption works quickly, it isn't so secure.

For example, if someone decrypts your data with a key which is 90% similar to the encryption key, the output data will also be 90% similar to the original data.

And this is bad. For example, if you're encrypting text, and someone gets a decryption key 90% similar to the one you used to encrypt, he'll probably be able to understand most of your text.

And I've also made one another encryption algorithm, which is this:

```
public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] bytes, string key)
{
    byte[] Key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key);

    byte sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Key.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += Key[i];
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (index >= key.Length) index = 0;
        bytes[i] += (byte)(Key[index] + sum);
        index++;
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

This algorithm is stronger than the first one. In this algorithm, even if someone's decryption key is 99% similar to your encryption key, the output data will still be totally different.

Every small difference in the key here will trigger a huge difference.
But the downside is, it sacrifices some speed. It's slower than the first algorithm, especially when encrypting big files.

So what do you think is better for encrypting data? The faster algorithm (first), or the second one? I'm talking about huge amounts of data, so speed is an important factor here.

Comment: Neither of those is what I would call "encryption"; be cautious... rolling your own crypto algorithms is a HUGE mistake. It takes a lot of experience and a lot of math to understand proper encryption well enough to know whether you are doing something really really silly.

Comment: On one hand I wonder whether this question would be better suited to [security.stackexchange.com](http://security.stackexchange.com/), but: the problem is - they could well *eat you alive* for doing that ^^^^ and calling it encryption (no, seriously, they would not be impressed)

Comment: But this is still kind of an encryption - You change specified data using a key, and you need the exact same key to decrypt the encrypted data. If you don't have the exact key, you'll NEVER be able to get the original data back.

So, even if you don't consider this an encryption, which algorithm is better?

Comment: I am not going to offer you a "which is better" on two algorithms that I consider equally insecure, as I would be doing you a dangerous disservice by validating your premise. The only answer I am willing to give is "investigate a known, investigated and proven encryption algorithm".

Comment: But why is it insecure, really? If you encrypt data with a certain key and you forget that key, you'll never be able to get the original data again (using these algorithms). So why are they insecure? Is it even possible to decrypt something that was encrypted using this encryption without the exact same key?

Comment: and that is exactly the analysis that would be proven mathematically for a genuine encryption algorithm. The best people to answer that, though, would be on security.SE

Comment: Yes, because you've described a substitution cipher, something which has been known to be vulnerable for a very very long time. Use AES in CBC or CTR mode if you want to have a modern cipher (only for confidentiality, not integrity or authenticity, use GCM mode for that).

Comment: OK, I do understand that encryption algorithms like AES are much more secure than my encryption algorithm. But can data that was encrypted with my algorithm be decrypted easily, without the key used to encrypt? If yes, how can it be decrypted?

Comment: @Travier well, the first thing I would want to look for is people sending files with predictable binary headers; pdf, zip, word, heck a lot of xml files; **just from that** it is probably possible to get a huge head-start on reversing the key from the first algorithm. As for the second: there are *entire papers* written on this topic. I am not a cryptography expert. All I can say is: I wouldn't trust that even for a moment.

Comment: OK, Thank you. I thought making encryption algorithms is something every programmer should be able to do at some decent level, but I guess I was wrong and there's a lot of math involved with making encryption algorithms and it's not that simple. Thanks anyway. I can't upvote you yet since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Even groups of researchers with 20 years of experience in the field don't always get algorithms right. One of the golden rules of cryptography is that you can always come up with an algorithm you can't break yourself, but that doesn't mean someone else can't break it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider neither stronger, both are trivially vulnerable to a [Known Plaintext Attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack), so if I know a file that is encrypted has a known header I can reverse engeneer the key with maybe about 20 minutes of programming to write the program that cracks the key and the program will likely only take seconds to run once written.

Even if I did not have have a plaintext to compare to but I know the encrypted blob is text of a known language both of these are also very vulnerable to attacks based on [Frequency Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_analysis).

Comment: And encryption algorithms such as RC4 and AES are not vulnerable to such attacks?

Comment: @Travier RC4 is slightly vulnerable to certain kinds of attacks; AES is not known to be vulnerable to any attacks despite decades of reserach.

Comment: But if AES is a symmetric-key encryption like RC4, how is it less vulnerable? Looking for known file headers with AES won't work?

Comment: @Travier Well, I guess it's not really appropriate to consider a cryptographic primitive by itself. Keystream reuse with a stream cipher like RC­4 (or AES in CTR mode) is catastrophic, so the secret key is combined with a random initialization vector. AES in ECB mode does not take an IV, and sure enough, it can leak information about the plaintext.